# A canvas to let through a given layer

Tags: unity, raycasting

I have two canvases, both of them having a UI element on them. 
At some point, both canvases will be active in the game (I just act like so, I want to make sure that my game works even if that's the case) and I want one of them to **never** block the other canvas's layer.

These two, let's say **Canvas1** is on layer *UI* and is responsible for character jumping. 
**Canvas2** is on layer *toggle time scale* and it's job is to switch between timescale 0 and 1. 
I want **Canvas2** to be ALWAYS accessible, so its layer, *toggle time scale* is NOT blocked by the first canvas. 
I tried messing around with the `Blocking Mask` but that didn't help, sometimes the ray still gets blocked out. How to set up those `Blocking Masks` for my canvases to work?

Comment: Not nearly enough information. Why is one canvas blocking the other? Do the graphics overlap? Why a separate canvas for each function? How does the user interact with the canvases - UI Buttons, something else? You can have two overlapping canvases with buttons on each, and as long as the graphics don't overlap neither canvas will block you from clicking on the other.

Comment: Have you looked around the Canvas' Script API page? There's a `renderOrder` value. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas-renderOrder.html

Comment: The `renderOrder` will do, though I removed the other canvas and instead used different scripts on just one canvas which solved the problem xd. 
But that's a clean solution,thanks for the input.